# Multiple Rows to Single Row Separate Cells in COGNOS

Tags: sql, rows, cognos, rdbms

I need to convert data stored on multiple rows into a single row with separate cells. I have seen several solutions for converting data stored across multiple rows into a single cell on a single row for CSV. However I have not seen any solutions showing how to display this data in separate cells in COGNOS 10.

In COGNOS 10 I have data listed as such:
[This is how i have the data currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWnFj.jpg)

It is two tables one of contact information and one of the member's information. However I need to display this data on one row with dependents such as spouse/child1/child2 etc as seperatas such:

[This is how I need the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkxjP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Spouse**

```
CASE [Dep Type]
WHEN 'Spouse' THEN [Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Spouse-Age**

```
CASE [Dep Type]
WHEN 'Spouse' THEN [Age - Pers] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Children**

```
CASE [Dep Type]
WHEN 'Child' THEN [Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child Count**

```
running-count([Children] for [Person],[ID])
```

Set the aggregate function to 'Calculated'

**Child1**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 1 THEN [Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child1-age**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 1 THEN [Age - Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child2**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 2 THEN [Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child2-age**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 2 THEN [Age - Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child3**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 3 THEN [Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child3-age**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 3 THEN [Age - Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child4**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 4 THEN [Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

**Child4-age**

```
CASE [Child Count]
WHEN 4 THEN [Age - Dep] 
ELSE null
END
```

This will create the columns you want. However, you will still have the same rows. To get rid of the rows, you can set the Aggregate Function property for all columns aside from Person and ID and Child Count to 'Maximum'. This, in conjunction with the default Auto-Group and Summarize property will roll everything up to the the two columns that define your grain, Person and ID.

Comment: Thank you!!! The only change I had to make to get exactly what I wanted was to add an AND statement to the children columns to check again that the status was child so that it didn't drop in spouse again (my child count was repeating the same count number when it would reach a spouse, not sure if this itself is preventable)

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. You'd want kick out null for runnning-count for rows where the [Dep Type] is Spouse. This can be done with a case statement. CASE [Dep Type] WHEN 'Child' THEN running-count([Children] for [Person],[ID]) ELSE null END